# How to assign class type to variables on dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and dart.

I want to transition with drawer like below.

```
class Page {
  String title;
  var page;
  Page(this.title, this.page);
}

class CommonDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  var _pages = [Page('Home', HomePage),
              Page('Form', FormPage)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (final p in _pages) genTile(p, context),
      ]

  ListTile genTile(Page page, context) {
      ~~~~~~~ Omitted ~~~~~~~~~~
      Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page.page()));
  }
}
```

but console says

```
Attempted to use type 'FormPage' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the FormPage constructor and forget the 'new' operator?
```

new page.page() is compile error.

Do anyone know right way of this on dart?

Comment: Use HomePage() like this and remove `page.page()` to `page.page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot abstract over classes in Dart.
With type variables (generics), you can abstract over *types*, but even that won't allow you to call constructors.

Try changing the code to:

```dart
class Page {
  String title;
  dynamic Function() createPage;
  Page(this.title, this.createPage);
}

class CommonDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  var _pages = [Page('Home', () => HomePage()),
              Page('Form', () => FormPage())];
...
      Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page.createPage()));
  }
}
```

(I'd use a different type than `dynamic` for the return type of `createPage`, but I can't see what the common supertype of `HomePage` and `FormPage` is).